# Android Google Maps crashing on second load

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I've looked through loads of questions, but can't seem to get any of them to work. From what I can understand, I need to destroy the map, so that it loads again next time I open it, but can't seem to work it out.

Currently what I have is below
xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map">

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in my main code I have:

```
public class ParkMap extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{

private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_park_map);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}

public void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
try {
        //SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
        mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            //mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            //.getMap();
            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        }
    }


    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The on destroy is something I tried to implement from what other posts I had read, but it isn't working. It is also crashing out when rotating the screen, therefore I believe it is just the change that it's not catching.

Thanks.

logcat:

```
04-08 15:36:20.043  13303-13303/com.zoome.zoomeapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.zoome.zoomeapp, PID: 13303
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zoome.zoomeapp/com.zoome.zoomeapp.ParkMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.zoome.zoomeapp.ParkMap.onCreate(ParkMap.java:98)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
```

Comment: how would i get it from the running app as its only happening when I upload the apk to the phone rather than when running in debug in android studio as desktop doesn't recognise the device to plug in

Answer (score 1):

If you want to destroy the fragment when the App closes, onDestroy will not always fire directly. You could move the removal code into onPause to test whether that will help you.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f != null){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f != null){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this approach:

have your custom Mapfragment class with the expected behaviour.

on your Fragmentactivity XML, create a FrameLayout and give it an id (map_container, as example).

create a method on your fragmentActivity that tries to replace the fragment (map_container)  inside the frame with your custom class. if it fails ( throw exception ) then try to add it ( replace and add are FragmentManager methods.)

i suspect your error is created because when you visit your activity the 2nd time,  it tries to add your map fragment to an already existing fragment, whereas it should be replacing it.

hope it helps.   and yes, the logcat would be appreciated to see what the error is.

please, try this approach:

```
FragmentManager fm = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
} else {
    fm = getChildFragmentManager();
}
SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment)   
fragment = findFragmentById(R.id.my_map_fragment);
mMap = fragment.getMap();
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but now getting a null pointer exception, not sure where I've gone wrong but edited code above

Comment: Tried in various and same issue is occurring in all

Comment: I'm getting cannot resolve method on getActivity, getChildFragmentManager and findFragmentById

Comment: make sure that you use the most recent AppCompat  library.

Comment: It's definitely in the graddle

Comment: try to add the most recent, make a project -> clean and a project -> rebuild, and try again. try removing the getActivity().

Answer (score 0):

I also have encountered with similar situation some days ago. You just have to comment that mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); and try your app again. And please let me know what happens.